# Machinist + RSpec and reserved words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, machinist

I have a blueprint:

```
Model.blueprint(:something) do
  name "Some name"
  context "some context"
end
```

"context" is an attribute of Model, but it is also a reserved word of RSpec. When I try to make and object I get ArgumentError on "context" line.

Any ideas how to overcome this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Unable to replicate this with Machinist 2.0.0.beta2.

Machinist works by overriding `method_missing?` and then assigning attributes based on those arguments. If rspec is somehow assigning a `context` method to Machinist's Lathe's objects, then that method will be called before `method_missing?`. If you're still experiencing this problem, you could try using `remove_method :context` before evaluating attributes:

```
Model.blueprint(:something) do
  remove_method :context
  name "Some name"
  context "some context"
  alias_method :context, :describe
end
```

I can't tell if that would work, as I can't replicate it locally, but I would give it a shot.